# Should I verify a JWT token information from a Database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, jwt

I'm currently trying to build a REST API using express, node, and MongoDB. Now for authentication, I'm using JWT.

Here is the code for checking JWT token

```
 const token = req.headers['authorization'];
 if (token){
    const tokens = token.split(' ');
    const key = tokens[1];
    jwt.verify(key, config.jwtKey, (err, authData) => {
        if (err){
            res.status(403).json({
                success: false,
                message: "Authentication2 failed"
            });
        }
        // User authenticated 
        // Do something
        next();
    });
  } else {
    res.status(403).json({
        success: false,
        message: "Authentication failed"
    });
}
```

Now, this code is working perfectly.

For making the JWT, here is the code

```
........
........
const token = jwt.sign(
{
   email: user[0]._email,
   userId: user[0]._id
}, config.jwtKey,{ expiresIn: "1d" });
........
........
```

Now my question is should I also verify the user by checking the existence of the user's information in the database to make it more secure?

For example, searching the `email` and `userId` to my database.

I'm using node, express, MongoDB, Mongoose, and JWT for this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an old question but I want to leave an answer:
Yes! Everytime your client make an api request, backend should verify both the validity of the token and the presence somewhere in your backend (for example a db table).
Consider always the most dangerous scenario: bank account
What happens if someone steal your device?
You should be able to invalidate the token from another device and change the password.

Comment: Although that concern can be solved by settings the JWT as a session and not as a permanent cookie, which is what every sensible portals would do. I would consider setting a periodic check on the token, that way you get mostly low latency but also added security.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of using a token is that the server can
verify it quickly without calling out to an external data store like MongoDB.

But if you're going to add a business login to your API authentication like a blacklist/whitelist of revoked tokens then you have to use a store to verify the token and user details, (will be slower than not doing a remote call for each token but you have to do it with low latency).

For low latency you have to use DB like Redis, Dynamodb would probably be fine and more secure without major latency between your DB and your API server.

Is not required to verify the signature with DB, and you can settle for JWT algorithm

Comment: For now, I don't have any plan to add any blacklist/whitelist feature. My question is if I successfully decode the token using the security key, that means the token is valid? I don't need to verify it by querying to the database

Comment: It will be more secure,                                                                                                 and will not be able to transfer the token between users. but is not required

Answer (score 0):

Verifying (the signature of) the token using the selected algorithm is enough to ensure that this user exists (or existed) on the system because it was the system who generated the token in the first place.

But there are cases when that's not enough, for example, blacklists as mentioned in Roy G's answer, or if the users' claims have been changed or completely deleted from the system but they are still using an old token (not expired yet), they could still have access to the system, so checking against DB would prevent that access.

Setting a small expiry date in combination with refresh tokens is generally a good practice to prevent those kinds of leaks.